# Default audio speaker problem

Tags: sound, kubuntu

I'm using Kubuntu 18.04 and I have an issue with the default audio speaker. I'm using Win7 Mixer and I'm happy with it GUI-wise but it has one issue which is on my nerve. Take a look at the below image:

[image]

As you can see I have an HDMI, Speaker, and a headset (HD 4.40BT). And as it is shown in the image, if I want to switch between them, I can click on the icon and choose "Default".

While this moves the green circle to clicked speaker, but audio will be played from the chosen speaker only if it is already playing. In other words, while the default state does change but the new processes that want to play audio they will fallback to the HDMI (always). And the only way I can listen to the audio on my headset is to start the audio and then switch to my headset.

This is really annoying because consider you are watching some YouTube video and want to listen to it on your headset. So you'll make the headset your default speaker. But once you click away from the video and go to another one or even pause for a second, the audio will be played from the HDMI again while the green circle is still on the headset!

Does anyone know how can I fix this problem?

**[UPDATE]**

While the default applet suffers from the same problem (exactly the same), `pavucontrol` only changes the default fallback speaker but as I mentioned earlier, the fallback speaker (the green circle) plays no role what-so-ever. So in other words, `pavucontrol` does nothing.

**[UPDATE]**

This is not going be a solution to the problem I've stated above myself. But I just wanted to mention that today the problem was resolved on its own without me doing anything about it!!!

I think there must have been some package updated which fixed the issue. But in anyway, now after I switch to an output, it will stick.

**[UPDATE]**

As if the situation was not strange enough, the problem that was resolved on its own, is not back. I'm not sure what's going on!

Comment: Does the default volume control applet in Plasma work correctly? Also have you tried pavucontrol

Comment: confirmed that these issues happen with `pauvcontrol` and the default applet. I'm an idiot and somehow posted it as an answer.